# AJAX response, getting undefined(in console normal JSON)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

The first

```
<form id="tweetInsert"  action="<? echo URL ?>homescreen/ajaxInsertTweet/" method="post">
    <textarea name="tweetText" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="submitTweet">Tweet</button>
</form>
<div class="row">
    <div id="tweets">
    </div>
</div>
```

The second

```
function ajaxInsertTweet()
{
    $tweet = $_POST["tweetText"];
    $stmtInsertTweet = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO tweets (tweet) VALUES (:tweet)");
    $stmtInsertTweet->execute(array(':tweet' => $tweet));
    $data = array('tweet' => $tweet );
    //print_r($data);
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
    //header("Location:".URL."homescreen");
}
```

The third

```
$("#tweetInsert").submit(function(ev){

    ev.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("action");

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    console.log("Output: " + data);

    $.post(url, data, function (o){
        $("#tweets").append("<div>"+o.tweet+"</div>");
    });
});
```

I try to load a post instantly inside of a div without refreshing the page, so i load a function on my javascript that does the post and stops the form from submit. I got a json array-> in my console, there is a json array like: `{"tweet","HERE IS THE POST OR SOMETHING ESLE"}`
but inside the div it gets called undefined.
In my `console.log("Output: "+data)` I got something like this:

> Output: tweetText=fgsdgfh
>
> Question: Why do i get a undefined inside my div? it should display the tweet

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: i added the question. Thanks for improving me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `dataType` argument to `$.post`.

It doesn't appear you are setting a `Content Type` header at server so response may be being interpreted as text.

This will tell `$.post` to expect `json` and to parse it internally

```
$.post(url, data, function (o){
    $("#tweets").append("<div>"+o.tweet+"</div>");
},'json');
```

Comment: what do you see in callback when you `console.log(o)` ?

Comment: if i put hello world in the textfield i got {tweet="hello word"}

but why do i got that? thats not the right json format...

Comment: doesn't make any sense to be honest

Comment: I just testet one thing, i postet the ev.preventDefault(); at the end of the function. then it works fine... i also deletet the "json" you told me to add, it doesn´t worked, so i pushed your answer

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$.post(url, data, function (o){
  $("#tweets").append("<div>"+o.tweet+"</div>");
});
```

to:

```
$.post(url, data, function (o){
  $("#tweets").append("<div>"+o.tweetText+"</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(url, data, function (o){
    $("#tweets").append("<div>"+o.tweet+"</div>");
});
```

The input parameter to the function is what is returned from the page.  So o is your returned HTML.  It is a string, not an object.

So the correct format would be

```
$.post(url, data, function (o){
    $("#tweets").append("<div>"+ o +"</div>");
});
```